# label is not growing when the text is longer

Tags: ios, swift2, autolayout, pure-layout

I want a view that is centered in the superview but that grows due the content in this case a label. But I don't want it to grow that it doesn't fit in the screen anymore so thats why I pin the left and right.

I've put on a test viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
import PureLayout

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container: UIView = {
        let container = UIView(forAutoLayout: ())
        container.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        container.clipsToBounds = true
        return container
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(forAutoLayout: ())
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        label.text = "This is a very very very long message"
        return label
    }()

    var rightView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(forAutoLayout: ())
        view.backgroundColor = .redColor()

        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.container.addSubview(self.label)
        self.view.addSubview(self.container)
        self.view.addSubview(self.rightView)

        self.container.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom, withInset: 20)
        self.container.autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis(.Vertical)
        self.container.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 36)
        self.container.layer.cornerRadius = 18
        self.container.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.rightView, withOffset: -20, relation: .LessThanOrEqual)
        self.container.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Left, withInset: 20, relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)
        self.container.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, forAxis: .Horizontal)

        self.label.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 10, 20))

        self.rightView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Right, withInset: 5)
        self.rightView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom, withInset: 20)
        self.rightView.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: 50)
        self.rightView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 60)
    }
}
```

The result of this is:

[image]

Why is the black view not growing until it can't due the left and right constraint? The number of lines is 1 and the ContentCompressionResistancePriority is on?

Comment: did you set the `label.numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: I now did but nothing changed.

Comment: have you given trailing and leading constraint?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the font size to fit the width of the UILabel (non-multiline):

`label.numberOfLines = 1;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
label.sizeToFit();`

You need dynamic changes in height means then you can do like following

[Dynamic UILabel changes](http://www.iosmike.com/2014/08/dynamically-resizing-labels-in-swift.html)

```
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 500;
```

you can use the above code for set preferred max width, All the best :)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It still doesn't grow. I don't get it. The text so long so actually the label should need to grow until it reaches the constraints of min 20 left and 20 right.

Comment: can you share the PureLayout code? it helps to get reliable solution

Comment: label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 500 just work perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What are the leading and trailing constraints on the label, you could set the leading constraint to an inequality like greater than or equal something like 5. If you're happy for the font to get smaller, you could set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to YES.

Comment: but I have that constraint on the left side. It must be 20 or bigger so that it can shrink when the textlabel is short but now the text label is big so it can grow until it comes to that constraint 20 px offset left.

Comment: okay so currently the left constraint is set to something like greater than or equal to 20? Could you tell me what the leading and trailing constraints are for the label?

Comment: I don't have any leading and trailing. I'm using the left and right. Is that not the same? Doesn't it only matter when you are support foreign languages?

Comment: yes the left and right constraint, could you tell me what then are currently set to, I've use to saying leading and trailing :p

Comment: No problem :-), yes this are the constraints currently:         self.container.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.rightView, withOffset: -20, relation: .LessThanOrEqual)
        self.container.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Left, withInset: 20, relation: .GreaterThanOrEqual)

Comment: sorry I see it in your code, so your container is offset by 20 and your label is offset by 10, maybe change your label's left edge the same as your container's left edge? Actually do you need the container, you want rounded edges, is that why you are using it?

Comment: The container has a black color like on the screenshot. The problem is that the label is not growing for some reason...

Comment: Could we continue this in chat? It looks like your container is probably what we need to change it's constraints. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122825/discussion-between-user1007522-and-jingjingtao).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
testLabel.text = "long text......."
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
testLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Set the `label.numberOfLines = 0` in your code then only it will expand based the text that you have.

Comment: I now have the numberOfLines on 0 but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you set height for the label and container that you are using? if set height pls remove it

Answer (score 0):

Im using xcode 4. I have tested this issue

Xcode screenshot

[image]

After running in iPhone 6

[image]
Since you have a view besides the label,It wont come delete or move the view to another layer so that the label resizes automatically with code

```
[labelName sizeToFit];
```